# Incorrect change point detection by FB Prophet

Tags: python-3.x, forecasting, trend, facebook-prophet

I have a time series data as follows:

```
           ds      y
0  2016-10-31   2000
1  2016-11-30   3000
2  2016-12-31   5000
3  2017-01-31   5000
4  2017-02-28   4000
5  2017-03-31   4500
6  2017-04-30  10000
7  2017-05-31   6500
8  2017-06-30   3500
9  2017-07-31   5500
10 2017-08-31   2000
11 2017-09-30   3000
12 2017-10-31  10000
13 2017-11-30   5000
14 2017-12-31   4000
15 2018-01-31   4500
16 2018-02-28   5000
17 2018-03-31   6500
18 2018-04-30   3500
19 2018-05-31   5500
20 2018-06-30   2000
21 2018-07-31   3000
22 2018-08-31  10000
23 2018-09-30   5000
24 2018-10-31   4000
25 2018-11-30   4500
26 2018-12-31   5000
27 2019-01-31   6500
28 2019-02-28   3500
29 2019-03-31   5500
```

I have applied FB Prophet change point detection algorithm to extract changepoints.

When I specify 5 changepoints in the code, I get the following changepoints:

```
5    2017-03-31
9    2017-07-31
14   2017-12-31
18   2018-04-30
23   2018-09-30
```

When I specify 7 changepoints in the code, I get the following changepoints:

```
3    2017-01-31
7    2017-05-31
10   2017-08-31
13   2017-11-30
16   2018-02-28
20   2018-06-30
23   2018-09-30
```

Why the algorithm does not detect point 6, 12, 22 where there is maximum change in the value as compared to the previous point?

My code below:

```
from fbprophet import Prophet
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


m = Prophet(growth='linear', n_changepoints = 7, changepoint_range=0.8, changepoint_prior_scale=0.5)
m.fit(df)

future = m.make_future_dataframe(freq = 'M', periods=3)
fcst = m.predict(future)

from fbprophet.plot import add_changepoints_to_plot
fig = m.plot(fcst)
a = add_changepoints_to_plot(fig.gca(), m, fcst)

m.changepoints
```

Answer (score 0):

Changepoints are a measure to calculate where the **trend** of the data changes. Your points 6, 12, and 22 are outliers, or perhaps holiday effects. Changepoints do nothing to account for this in a reliable way. Taken your 7 changepoints example prophet analyzed the following trendlines:

```
2016-10-31 - 2016-12-31 
2016-12-31 - 2017-05-31 
2017-05-31 - 2017-08-31 
2017-08-31 - 2017-11-30 
2017-11-30 - 2018-02-28 
2018-02-28 - 2018-06-30 
2018-06-30 - 2018-09-30 
2018-09-30 - 2019-03-31 (and beyond)
```